# Cannot save file in init.m

Tags: files-and-directories

I want to use [ProjectForMMA package](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/ProjectForMMA.m),but it throws an error.

[image]

But I want to import this package if `Kernel` started.

So I want to modify `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`:

Add `NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[],FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.nb"}]];` to `init.m`.

[image]

Re-open Mathematica ,it throws an error...

[image]

So how to import [ProjectForMMA package](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/ProjectForMMA.m) when I opened MMA?

***PS:Only in Mathematica 11.1.0 has this problem.11.0.0 runs ok.***

Comment: We usually reserve the bugs tag for when others have confirmed the behavior as a bug.  I'm no expert on the interaction between the front end and the kernel, but what would you expect `EvaluationNotebook[]` to evaluate to in the kernel's `init.m`?

Comment: As Kuba said, `EvaluationNotebook[]` makes no sense in `init.m` because the evaluation is not being done in a notebook.  Generally, no notebook operations should be present in `init.m` because this is a file that is run on kernel startup, and the kernel can run independently of the front end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58456/discussion-between-kuba-and-partida).